# Angular routeParams is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use routeParams in my JS but it always passed in as undefined.

```
app.controller('ShowKey', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $log) {

  $log.info('SomeCtrl - starting up, yeah!');
  $log.info($routeParams);

  $scope.getKey = function() {
    $log.info($routeParams);
  };
});
```

Is there anything else what I need to set other than calling the app.controller with routeParams?

Comment: That is correct, assuming you are injecting `ngRoute` into your module, but you should be seeing an error when trying to configure `$routeProvider` in your app config. Assuming that is in place, can you post the route configuration(s) that are navigating you to this controller?

Comment: @Brocco I think this is what is missing. I need to configure  routeParams before I could use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Have you consider any routeParams in your config anyway ?
2- if you want to get your routeParams in your config , well , you cant,

---you must use :

$route.current.params , instead

```
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/path/:yourRouteParam'
       templateUrl:"your template url address",
        controller:'your controller',
        resolve: {
            resolbeObject: function($route){
             //**here you cannot use $routeParam to get "yourRouteParam"** property
            // you must use : $route.current.params
            }
        }
    })
    });
```

But in your controller you can get yourRouteParam with $route.params , just if you have defined route params in your route confige like this :

```
       $routeProvider.when('/path/:**yourRouteParam**
```

**NOTE**        if you want to define any route param you must use(:), not (?)